# Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-xxx: Connection refused in docker container after restart host

Tags: docker, sockets, docker-compose, dockerfile, dbus

I'm having trouble connecting to the correct abstract unix socket inside a docker container after the host is restarted.

At container creation, I set the container's `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to the current value of the host's `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. Everything works as expected. After the host is restarted, its `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` changed but the container still tried to connects to the old socket. To be more specific:

1. host's current `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is `/tmp/dbus-ABC`
2. start container X and set its `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to `/tmp/dbus-ABC` (same as host)
3. restart host
4. host's new `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is `/tmp/dbus-XYZ`
5. restart container X
6. get `"Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-ABC: Connection refused"` inside container because the host's new `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` is `/tmp/dbus-XYZ`

I know can fix this by update the value of container's DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS every time after I restart the host. But is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can just pass the environment variable to the container in the run command.

I.e:

```
docker run .... -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).